# Custom Fields with get_post()

Tags: custom-field, get-post

I am using get_post() to call a single Wordpress post using it's post ID. I have successfully managed to pull the content / title of the post but would like to also pull custom fields also.

The code below is how I declare custom fields in a standard wp_query:

```
$customField = (get_post_meta($post->ID, "_mcf_customField", true));
```

And my get_post code below:

```
                $my_id = 401491;
                $post_id = get_post($my_id);
                $customField = get_post_meta($post_id, "_mcf_customField", true); // I do not think this is correct
                $content = $post_id ->post_content;

                echo $content;
                echo $customField; // No output
```

I believe the customField variable above is declared incorrectly, cannot seem to find anything in the Codex that sheds any light though. Does anyone have experience using Custom fields with get_post?

Comment: I think, get_post_meta should be called with $my_id instead of $post_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know the ID, so just use it:

```
$customField = get_post_meta($my_id, "_mcf_customField", true);
```

But only for reference, if you want to get the ID from the object:

```
$customField = get_post_meta($post_id->ID, "_mcf_customField", true);
```

Comment: Thanks bud, used first suggestion and works perfectly. Didn't need to get_post being called by $post_id.

Comment: That's true! Once you have the ID, you can use mostly post functions with it without querying. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

With ACF, i am able to do this:

```
$my_field = get_field('my_field', $post->ID);
```

Reference: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: why the downvote? please explain, i am happy to improve my answer if needed.